# Why is my Program is Returning (null) and Gibberish rather than the Intended Output

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

Windows NT crashed.
I am the Blue Screen of Death.
No one hears your screams.

I am writing a program in which I have to read in haikus from a file, after which I must store all of the five syllable lines into one array and all of the seven syllable lines into another. I have to use an array of char* pointers to store each set of lines. I also can only allocate enough space at each pointer for the actual length of the string. As a result, for the haiku above, I should malloc 20, 31, and 28 bytes for those three lines, respectively (including the \0).
Once all the lines have been read in from the file and stored into the appropriate arrays, I must use a random number generator to pick a set of three lines to print to the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("This number of arguments is incorrect.");

        return 1;
    }

    FILE *oldfile, *newfile;

    char const *newfilename = "myhaiku.txt";
    int linecntr = 0, fivesyllines = 0, svnsyllines = 0;
    int freearr, newhaiku;

    // char **fivesylptrs = malloc(200 * sizeof(char *));
    // char **svnsylptrs = malloc(200 * sizeof(char *));
    char *fivesylptrs[200], *svnsylptrs[100];
    char line[129];

    srand(time(NULL));

    /* for (fivesyllines = 0; fivesyllines < 200; fivesyllines++)
    {
        fivesylptrs[fivesyllines] = (char *) malloc(129 * sizeof(char));
    }

    for (svnsyllines = 0; svnsyllines < 200; svnsyllines++)
    {
        svnsylptrs[svnsyllines] = (char *) malloc(129 * sizeof(char));
    } */

    oldfile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    newfile = fopen(newfilename, "w");

    if (oldfile)
    {
        while (fgets(line, 129, oldfile) != NULL)
        {
            linecntr++;

            if ((linecntr % 2) != 0)
            {
                // printf("%s", line);

                fivesylptrs[fivesyllines] = (char *)malloc(129 * sizeof(char));

                if (fivesylptrs[fivesyllines] == NULL)
                {
                    printf("The memory for the five syllable strings wasn't allocated properly.\n");
                }

                strcpy(fivesylptrs[fivesyllines], line);

                // printf("%s", fivesylptrs[fivesyllines]);

                fivesylptrs[fivesyllines] = fivesylptrs[fivesyllines + 1];

                // fivesyllines++;
            }
            else if ((linecntr % 2) == 0 && line[0] != '\n')
            {
                // printf("%s", line);

                svnsylptrs[svnsyllines] = (char *)malloc(129 * sizeof(char));

                if (svnsylptrs[svnsyllines] == NULL)
                {
                    printf("The memory for the seven syllable strings wasn't allocated properly.\n");
                }

                strcpy(svnsylptrs[svnsyllines], line);

                // printf("%s", svnsylptrs[svnsyllines]);

                svnsylptrs[svnsyllines] = svnsylptrs[svnsyllines + 1];

                // svnsyllines++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This file could not be opened, please try again.\n");
    }

    for (newhaiku = 0; newhaiku < 10; newhaiku++)
    {
        printf("%s", fivesylptrs[(rand() % 200)]);
        printf("%s", svnsylptrs[(rand() % 100)]);
        printf("%s", fivesylptrs[(rand() % 200)]);
    }

    fclose(oldfile);
    fclose(newfile);

    for (freearr = 0; freearr < 200; freearr++)
    {
        free(fivesylptrs[freearr]);
    }
    for (freearr = 0; freearr < 100; freearr++)
    {
        free(svnsylptrs[freearr]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried quite a few different techniques to resolve the errors that I'm pretty sure I'm having with malloc, but I can't figure out exactly what I'm doing incorrectly. I would really appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Does crash happen when you uncomment those for loops?

Comment: `fivesyllines` is not being incremented.

Comment: @Sandeep Does fivesylptrs[fivesyllines] = fivesylptrs[fivesyllines + 1]; not increment fivesyllines?

Comment: @rafix07 I don't think I understand what you're getting at, could you please clarify?

Comment: @P.W Yes, the program closes without returning anything when I uncomment those two loops.

Comment: @confusedstudent No it doesn't. It just assignes value of array fivesylptrs  at index fivesyllines+1 to index fivesyllines. for incrementing you need to do `fivesyllines = fivesyllines + 1;` or `fivesyllines++;`

Comment: Remove `svnsylptrs[svnsyllines] = svnsylptrs[svnsyllines + 1];` and uncomment `// svnsyllines++;` , and do the same for `fivesylptrs`.

Answer (score 1):

`svnsyllines` and `fivesyllines` are not incremented so you allocate `svnsylptrs` and `fivesylptrs` at index 0 multiple times (leak). The rest of the array is never allocated even though you access it.

Comment: I uncommented the lines where I increment those two variables and commented out the lines directly above each of them, but I still have a leak.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

1. Array indices for the arrays `svnsylptrs` and `fivesylptrs` are not incremented in the respective blocks.
2. The size of the array `svnsylptrs` is 200. But the `for` loop at the end only frees the first 100 elements. This will cause a memory leak.

`for (freearr = 0; freearr < 100; freearr++) //This should check upto 200
 {
    free(svnsylptrs[freearr]);
 }`

Comment: 1. I updated my code to increment svnsyllines and fivesyllinesm but I still have a leak.

2. The size of the array should be 100, I have corrected that. Additionally, I am not using those initial for loops to allocate memory, I have those commented out.

Comment: Are you freeing all the 200 elements like suggested in point 2 of the answer?